# How to set TTL to make Redis keys expire in flink-connector-redis?

Tags: java, maven, redis, apache-flink

I am using this Flink Redis sink version dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.bahir</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-connector-redis_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is my current code:

```
public static class MyRedisMapper implements RedisMapper<Tuple2<String, String>>{
    @Override
    public RedisCommandDescription getCommandDescription() {
        return new RedisCommandDescription(RedisCommand.HSET, "MY_REDIS_KEY");
    }

    @Override
    public String getKeyFromData(Tuple2<String, String> data) {
        return data.f0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getValueFromData(Tuple2<String, String> data) {
        return data.f1;
    }
}

FlinkJedisPoolConfig conf = new FlinkJedisPoolConfig.Builder().setHost("127.0.0.1").build();

DataStream<String> myStream = ...;
myStream.addSink(new RedisSink<Tuple2<String, String>>(conf, new MyRedisMapper());
```

Currently after writing data to Redis, the data will stay there and won't expire.

I hope to set [Redis TTL](https://redis.io/commands/TTL) to make keys expire.

The [official doc](https://bahir.apache.org/docs/flink/current/flink-streaming-redis/) is very simple.

After reading it, I still have no clue.

How to set TTL to make my Redis keys expire? Thanks!

---

**UPDATE:**

When I check the Java class I am using, I only have

```
public RedisCommandDescription(org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.redis.common.mapper.RedisCommand redisCommand, java.lang.String additionalKey) { /* compiled code */ }
public RedisCommandDescription(org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.redis.common.mapper.RedisCommand redisCommand) { /* compiled code */ }
```

However, I found a [pull request](https://github.com/apache/bahir-flink/pull/66) that add TTL to `HSET` and also a new `SETEX` command, got merged in Oct 2019.

I didn't see `SETEX` got added in the doc https://bahir.apache.org/docs/flink/current/flink-streaming-redis/

Also, I didn't find [this line](https://github.com/apache/bahir-flink/blob/b618a77cca2e44be86f18607e21a6b2d2bf8dd39/flink-connector-redis/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/redis/common/mapper/RedisCommandDescription.java#L68) that in the part of pull request:

```
public RedisCommandDescription(RedisCommand redisCommand, String additionalKey, Integer additionalTTL)
```

in my current version dependency.

I didn't find a new **flink-connector-redis** version in the [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.bahir/flink-connector-redis).

Where can I find and use the latest version of **flink-connector-redis**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately version 1.0 [is the latest release](https://bahir.apache.org/downloads/flink/) so you'll need to build the connector from the sources

Best,
D.

Comment: Thanks David! I followed up at [GitHub](https://github.com/apache/bahir-flink/pull/66) and created a [JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BAHIR-279) to see if the team can help publish a new version.